# How to combine items from two ConcurrentBags?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, bag, set-union

For `List`s I could use the `Union` method:

```
var finalCollection = new List<MyType>();
var list1= new List<MyType>();
var list2 = new List<MyType>();
finalCollection = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

But when I try to do the same with `ConcurrentBag`s,

```
var finalCollection = new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();
var bag1= new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();
var bag2= new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();
finalCollection = bag1.Union(bag2);
```

I get:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< MyType>" to "System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag"

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the problem is you are trying to Union the elements into a new `ConcurrentBag`

What you actually get after the union is an `IEnumerable` of `MyType`

To get back a `ConcurrentBag` try doing it like so:

```
var bag1 = new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();
var bag2 = new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();
var finalCollection = new ConcurrentBag<MyType>(bag1.Union(bag2));
```

Comment: I just want to mention that be aware of possible missing items if some items will be added or removed from one of the bags during Union process. ConcurrentBag.GetEnumerator will make a snapshot.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks. But I think I can't use "new" as I am actually inside a Parallel ForEach loop. The instantiations have already happened outside the loop.

Comment: @KWC that's not a problem.You can do this instead:

finalCollection.AddRange(bag1.Union(bag2));

Comment: @Rad , the ConcurrentBag does not seem to have the AddRange method?

Comment: @KWC my mistake. I had used a list in my sample. I can't think of any other way of populating a pre-created ConcurrentBag other than doing the Union to get an IEnumerable<MyType> from the first two bags then iterating through that IEnumerable in a loop calling finalCollection.Add()

Comment: @Rad, Thanks. That's what I did at the end. Was initially just thinking if there is an easy way like the ToList method. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The `var` in...

```cs
var finalCollection = new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();
```

...might be hiding what the problem is.  Expanding it (mentally or explicitly) to...

```cs
ConcurrentBag<MyType> finalCollection = new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();
```

...should make it clear why `bag1.Union(bag2)`, which returns an `IEnumerable<MyType>`, can't be assigned to `finalCollection`.  Note that in Visual Studio (Code) if you hover the mouse over the `var` keyword a tooltip will show you the variable's inferred type.

Also, your two code snippets aren't quite "the same"; in the first you are calling `ToList()` to create a `List<>` from the result of `Union()`, but in the second you trying to assign the result of `Union()` directly to a `ConcurrentBag<>` variable without doing anything to actually *make it* a `ConcurrentBag<>`, which [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60998476/150605) shows how to do.  If you removed the `.ToList()` from the first code snippet you would get a similar error.

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried to defined the variable explicitly. But that didn't help. And I am also aware that the thing I did was not quite "the same", that I used `.ToList()`method at the first example. I couldn't find anything like `.ToConcurrentBag()` or something.

Comment: Changing the variable declaration to `ConcurrentBag<MyType> finalCollection` wouldn't eliminate the error, it just makes it clear that the type of the variable is more-derived than what you're trying to assign to it, which isn't allowed.